# Copy and Paste to Blank Rows until Blank in Other Column

Tags: vba, excel, copy, paste

I am trying to copy and paste A8:P8 in to the Blank Rows (as per pic below) until the data in column Q is blank - is there a VBA which can do this? I need to do this on multiple tabs so the row number will be variable.

[image: Example Picture]

Comment: That not how it works here. We won't write code for you. Make an attempt and we can help out where you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Although you could accomplish this with VBA, have you tried just using cell formulae?

For example, in the first empty cell in column A you'd put:

```
=$A$8
```

then the same for each other cell in the row, changing the column letter.

Then select all of the cells with formula and double-clicking the autofill handle which will copy the formula down to the last row with data in the adjacent column.